# React Portal input change removes elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created this pen to demo it: https://codepen.io/no1melman/pen/WWyJqQ

essentially I have this portal:

```
const ChatArea = ({ children }) => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.classList.add('chatbox')
  const root = document.getElementById("rootus");

  useEffect(() => {
    root.appendChild(el);
    return () => root.removeChild(el);
  }, []);

  return createPortal(children, el);
};
```

And Use like:

```
const ChatBox = () => {
  const [ reply, setReply ] = useState('');
  const handleReply = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setReply(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <ChatArea>
      <div className="chat-title">Bot Convo</div>

      <div className="chat-convo"></div>

      <div className="chat-reply">
        <input type="text" value={reply} onChange={handleReply} />
        <button>Send</button>
      </div>
    </ChatArea>
  )
}
```

For some reason as you start typing the body of the chatbox seems to disappear... I've put logs into the `useEffect` to see if that was causing it, but it didn't show what I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

The first issue is

```
useEffect(() => {
    root.appendChild(el);
    return () => root.removeChild(el);
  }, []);
```

Now as per the hooks principle the dependency should match the used variables inside the hook. If not used react will not run the effect next time.

SO in your case when you click on open chat it opens up the chat box. the effect ran and rendered the portal with the input box.

When you have typed the first letter and onChange happened

It triggered the rerender of ChatArea, which should have ideally run the effect again, but didn't run as dependency array is blank and react has not idea as to when re-render.so the effect ran once for the first time where chatArea  ran UI mounted and next time, the effect did not run as  dependency array is blank.

This line :

return createPortal(children, el);  // is referring to the new el which is created
but not attached to DOM. Hence nothing is visible on UI inside chatbox.

Refer this link: [do not miss dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) React hooks FAQs sections they are great :)

2nd issue:

Ideally, new div should not be created every time. Persist the "div" element across consecutive rerenders

See this implementation: I know there can be other ways of implementing it. 
Feedbacks are welcome.

```js
const {
  render,
  createPortal
} = ReactDOM;
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef
} = React;

const ChatArea = ({
  children
}) => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.classList.add('chatbox')
  // This el above will be different in each render 

  // root will remain same, ideally root and chatdiv should be passed as props
  const root = document.getElementById("rootus");

  // this val and setVal is done to toggle render the chart area after
  // chatDiv is updated
  const [val, setVal] = useState(true)


  const chatDiv = useRef(null)

  // First useEffect to persist the div 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chatDiv.current) {
      chatDiv.current = el
      setVal(!val)
    }
  }, [chatDiv])

  useEffect(() => {
    root.appendChild(chatDiv.current);
    return () => {
      return root.removeChild(chatDiv.current)
    }; // you are removing it 
  }, [chatDiv, root]);

  if (chatDiv.current) {
    return createPortal(children, chatDiv.current)
  }
  return null
  // In your case as the return happened first and found out the el

};

const ChatBox = () => {
  const [reply, setReply] = useState('');
  const handleReply = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setReply(e.target.value);
  }
  return ( <
    ChatArea >
    <
    div className = "chat-title" > Bot Convo < /div>

    <
    div className = "chat-convo" > < /div>

    <
    div className = "chat-reply" >
    <
    input type = "text"
    value = {
      reply
    }
    onChange = {
      handleReply
    }
    /> <
    button > Send < /button> <
    /div> <
    /ChatArea>
  )
}

const NavBar = ({}) => ( <
  div className = "navbar" >
  <
  div > Home < /div> <
  div > Somewhere < /div> <
  /div>
);
const Main = () => {
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);
  const openChat = () => {
    setShowChat(true);
  };
  const chatterbox = showChat ? ( < ChatBox / > ) : null;

  return ( <
    div className = "container" >
    <
    h2 > Main < /h2> <
    p >
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.The point of
    using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more - or - less normal distribution of
    letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their
    default model text, and a search
    for 'lorem ipsum'
    will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose(injected humour and the like). <
    /p> <
    p style = {
      {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    } >
    <
    button onClick = {
      openChat
    } > Open Chat < /button> <
    /p> <
    p style = {
      {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    } >
    {
      chatterbox
    } < /p> <
    /div>
  );
};
const App = ({}) => ( <
  div className = "app" >
  <
  NavBar / >
  <
  Main / >
  <
  /div>
);

render( < App / > , document.getElementById("rootus"));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Raleway;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rootus {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar>div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar>div:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.chatbox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.chat-title {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.chat-convo {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.chat-reply {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.chat-reply>input {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.chat-reply>button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rootus">

</div>
```

> Ui was not coming up proper in the stackoverflow code snippet, so I
>   had to edit somethings in styling. you can have a look at code pen
>   [codepen link](https://codepen.io/stack26/pen/eoKLez?editors=1111)according to your  original  styling